# fancy box only for anchor which dont have parent class "stackfive"

Tags: jquery, class, fancybox, parent-child

i want to apply fancybox event only for those anchor tags which dont have parent class "stackfive" what i have to do?
I have tried following steps but no luck.

```
$("a#group.parent("[class!='stackfive']")").fancybox({
});

!$("a#group").parent().hasClass("stackfive").fancybox({
});
```

please help..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a#group').each(function () {
    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('stackfive')) {
      $(this).fancybox({
//fancy box settings
});
    }
});
```

Now its working but if there are too many **a#group** then **.each** will take too much time so can any one suggest other efficient method...

Comment: This `a#group` makes me think you are using the same ID for several elements in your document, which is not a good idea. Use *classes* instead